# Flutter PageTransitionSwitcher is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to add an animation when transitioning from user's profile page to the previous page. so I used PageTransitionSwitcher as already I'm using animations package for another purpose in the app.This is how I implemented it inside the back button of the page.When I click on back button it is not working.

```
onPress: () => {
                 
                    PageTransitionSwitcher(
                      transitionBuilder: (child, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                          SharedAxisTransition(animation: animation, secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                              transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal),
                      child: NewMainTabs(),
                    )
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to build the route.

```html
import 'package:animations/animations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Route buildSharedZAxisTransitionPageRoute(Widget Function(BuildContext) builder,{RouteSettings? settings}) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
      settings: settings,
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => builder(context),
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        return SharedAxisTransition(
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
          animation: animation,
          secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
          transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.scaled,
          child: child,
        );
      });
    }
```

Then you can call upper  function to create your route and push it into navigator or just rebuild with another widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return PageTransitionSwitcher(
  transitionBuilder: (
    Widget child,
    Animation<double> primaryAnimation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return FadeThroughTransition(
      child: child,
      animation: primaryAnimation,
      secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
    );
  },
  child: MyWidget(),
);
```

or

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
          buildSharedZAxisTransitionPageRoute(
              (_) => const MyWidget())
```